# What's the most intuitive control to sort a bar chart?

Tags: charts, graphs, sort

I'm designing a feature that includes a bar chart which needs to be sorted in a few different of ways. I'm exploring a few options on what's the most intuitive way to achieve this.

A. Tabs
B. Combo box 
C. Combo box at the top of bar label's column
D. Sort button next to the bar labels that opens up the a sort selection (similar to B and C).

Of the above approaches, which would make most sense? I'm open to other approaches as well.

[image: options A-D]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit vague but still..

Tabs aren't suitable here. Tabs are associated with different content areas, when I switch to another tab I go to another domain (or, often, sub-sub-subdomain), it would be very unusual to use them for controlling sorting.

B and C are the same in terms of UX approach, and the specific location of the control can only be suggested as part of the overall system design, it can't be taken out of context like this.

D seems redundant, but it also needs to be taken in context, there might be cases when it's justifiable.

I suggest that you explore some systems with bar charts, try to analyze their solutions (why did they pick that particular solution, what use cases are they handling), and learn from that.

In any case one parameter that will affect your decision is the number of options. If it's two, I would try to look into a toggle switch or a pair of radio buttons. Three is borderline. Four and more - some kind of dropdown as you suggested.

Also look at the usage frequency. If it's something that's supposed to be used very rarely, then a popup dialog is also an option